# System requirement for Dual Boot Doubt

Tags: dual-boot

I have a i3 processor at 3 GHz and 2 GB Ram is it good for a win 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot

Answer (score 1):

There are no CPU, Ram or processor requirements to dual boot. You'll just need the minimum for each operating system on its own.

You will, however, need more *hard drive space*. You'll want at least ~8GB for Ubuntu and probably at least ~15GB for Windows. This does not count any files you have, which you'll want more space for. If you already have Windows installed, I would recommend having at least 15GB free space for Ubuntu, software and some small files.

As per the link Karel posted in comments, you may want to try Xubuntu or Lubuntu rather than Ubuntu itself, due to your Ram/CPU. Dual booting or not will not change what Ubuntu flavor you want to install. See [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/q/206407/115738) for more info.

See https://askubuntu.com/a/319630/115738